# CodeIgniter - Additional dbforge / migration fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im having trouble figuring out this migrations business for CodeIgniter ... I cant find any decent documentation that explains additional field elements like current_timestamp, default datetime values etc etc

I was wondering if someone could help me out to translate the following into proper dbforge->add_field  arrays

I need the following 2

```
`last_login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and

```
`created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I have copied these from the SQL insert statement from the tank_auth library.

But i want to put it into migrations now.

Cheers,

Answer (score 7):

for number 1 you can use

```
$this->dbforge->add_field('last_login TIMESTAMP');
```

or

```
$data = array(
 'type' => 'TIMESTAMP'
);
```

This auto inserts ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Yes, totally checked. Adding 'type' => TIMESTAMP auto inserts ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be out of luck. These are the [available options to dbforge](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html):

> Additionally, the following key/values can be used:
>
> ```
> unsigned/true : to generate "UNSIGNED" in the field definition.
> default/value : to generate a default value in the field definition.
> null/true : to generate "NULL" in the field definition. Without this, the field will >     default to "NOT NULL".
> auto_increment/true : generates an auto_increment flag on the field. Note that the >     field type must be a type that supports this,
> such as integer
> ```

You may have to pass a standard query. [`$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide//database/queries.html) may be what you need.

Comment: Thats interesting thanks for that ... how would i put those statements into a standard CI query?