# How to create DATETIME filed in MySQL with CodeIgniter DB Forge?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I'm learning CodeIgniter and now I wan to create MySQL table with DATETIME field.

I have this code in Install_Model.php

```
    $Fields = array(
      'ID' => array(
      'Type' => 'INT',
      'Constraint' => 10,
      'Unsigned' => TRUE,
      'Auto_Increment' => TRUE
    ),
      'Username' => array(
      'Type' => 'VARCHAR',
      'Constraint' => '255'
    ),
      'Password' => array(
      'Type' => 'VARCHAR',
      'Constraint' => '255'
    ),
      'AddDate' => array(
      'Type' => 'DATETIME'
    )
  );

  $this->dbforge->add_key('ID', TRUE);
  $this->dbforge->add_field($Fields);
  $this->dbforge->create_table('Admins', TRUE);
  echo 'Table Admins created successfully!<br/>';
```

When I execute this code I get this error:

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'AddDate' at row 1

And in filed `AddDate` content is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

How I can fix problem, and make `AddDate` content current timestamp?

I tried to set DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but then CodeIgniter returns error in SQL query :(

Comment: I am not sure if this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685986/codeigniter-additional-dbforge-migration-fields

Answer (score 0):

Try

`'AddDate' => array(
            'type'       => 'datetime',
            'default'    => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        )`

Comment: Doesn't work, it writes `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to column :(

Answer (score 0):

```
'AddDate' => array(
        'type'       => 'TIMESTAMP',
    )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please explain your answer. Why does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Add these in your model, it will automatically add current datetime on creation, updation adn deletion etc.

```
protected $createdField  = 'AddDate';
protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';
```